# Create adjacency matrix calculate distance between many city

Tags: python, numpy, dataframe

I am currently have a data like this

```
                   0                     1        2
0   Ho Chi Minh City               Dalat   1146.72
1  Ho Chi Minh City               Mui Ne    220.00
2  Mui Ne                         Dalat    340.00
```

I want to create a matrix that can display double array like

```
                     HCM                Dalat        Mui Ne
    HCM               0                 1146.72       220
    Dalat             1146.72           0             340
    Mui Ne            220               340           0
```

There are more cities in my datafarme. I can understand the adjacency matrix, however I don't know how to display to the adjacency matrix, and code can understand that HCM to HCM is 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a fast way to do this with numpy:
In the following code `d` is the numpy array of distances like it is in the dataframe and `n` is the number of cities.

```
d = np.array([1146.72, 220, 340])
n = 3

upperIndices = np.triu_indices(n, k=1)
lowerIndices = np.tril_indices(n, k=-1)

distanceMatrix = np.zeros((n,n))
distanceMatrix[upperIndices] = d
distanceMatrix[lowerIndices] = d
```

Result:

```
array([[   0.  , 1146.72,  220.  ],
       [1146.72,    0.  ,  340.  ],
       [ 220.  ,  340.  ,    0.  ]])
```

Note that this will only work if the list of disctances is ordered correctly.

Comment: Sir, what happened if I have a list of city name?

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a list with all different cities first.
2. Number of elements in your list as n
3. Create a numpy array as `x = np.zeros((n,n))`
4. For each record in your dataframe, find the city indexes from the list. Let me denote as i,j and the distance as d then update `x[i,j]=d`

Hope this will help.